# Java equivalent of Python's __eq__ and __bool__

Tags: java, python, equivalent

I'd like to perform equivalency and boolean tests quickly on my Java instances.  How I do the equivalent of the Python3 code in Java?  (notice that there is no reference to any attribute - just the instance itself)

**test.py**

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n = n
    def __eq__(self, num):
        return self.n == num
    def __bool__(self):
        return True

def main():
    t = Number(10)
    if t == 10:
        print("Equivalency")
    if t:
        print("Boolean")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 test.py
Equivalency
Boolean
```

Comment: Java has no operator overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override `==`, nor can you implement a `__bool__` equivalent. However, you most definitely *should* override `equals()` (and probably `hashCode()` as well). This equals method will be used by *everything* to compare object equality. The only time you would use `==` is if you wanted to see if two variables were pointing to the same object in memory.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    ...
}
```